# How to design an abstract reader in Scala Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, implicit

The problem is the following:
We have multiple file types that we want to parse with custom logic. Suppose we have the following types: CSV, JSON, BIN. For this I created an enumeration using the enumeratum library

```scala
import enumeratum._
import scala.collection.immutable

/**
  * Implementation of enumeratum for various input file types.
  * See more at: https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum
  */
sealed trait InputFileType extends EnumEntry

object InputFileType extends Enum[InputFileType] {

  val values: immutable.IndexedSeq[InputFileType] = findValues

  case object CSV extends InputFileType

  case object JSON extends InputFileType

  case object BIN extends InputFileType

}
```

For each `InputFileType` there exists a corresponding reader:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.input.PortableDataStream

class CSVReader(filename: String, file: String)
class JSONReader(filename: String, file: String)
class BINReader(filename: String, file: PortableDataStream)
```

Since they should share some common steps and have similar structure I was thinking to have a superclass for them where we have some steps that each reader should implement. But the `file` input can vary so I thought of making an ADT for it. Therefore:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.input.PortableDataStream

sealed trait File
object File {

  case class Text(file: String) extends File

  case class BinaryStream(file: PortableDataStream) extends File

}

abstract class AbstractReader(filename: String, file: File) {
  def doStep1: Seq[String]
  def process: Result
}

class CSVReader(filename: String, file: String) extends AbstractReader(filename, Text(file)) {
  override def doStep1: Seq[String] = ???
  override def process: Result = ???
}

class JSONReader(filename: String, file: String) extends AbstractReader(filename, Text(file)) {
  override def doStep1: Seq[String] = ???
  override def process: Result = ???
}

class BINReader(filename: String, file: PortableDataStream) extends AbstractReader(filename, BinaryStream(file)) {
  override def doStep1: Seq[String] = ???
  override def process: Result = ???
}

//where
case class Data(col1: String, col2: Int)
type Result = List[Data]
```

Now my idea was to create a `SparkReader` for reading them into `RDD[Result]`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

class SparkReader(spark: SparkSession, fileType: String) extends Serializable {
  def readTextFile(path: String): RDD[(String, String)] = spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles(path)
  def readBinaryFile(path: String): RDD[(String, PortableDataStream)] = spark.sparkContext.binaryFiles(path)
}
object SparkReader {
  def apply(spark: SparkSession, fileType: String): RDD[Result] = InputFileType.withNameInsensitive(fileType) match {
    case InputFileType.CSV => new SparkReader(spark, fileType).readTextFile(path)
      .map{case (filename: String, file: String) => new CSVReader(filename, file).process}
    case InputFileType.JSON => new SparkReader(spark, fileType).readTextFile(path)
      .map{case (filename: String, file: String) => new JSONReader(filename, file).process}
    case InputFileType.BIN => new SparkReader(spark, fileType).readBinaryFile(path)
      .map{case (filename: String, file: PortableDataStream) => new BINReader(filename, file).process}
  }
}
```

However I am not satisfied with this solution because in the end there is a lot of code duplication, and I would like a design which is able to implicitly decide which reader to use.
In the end I would like to instantiate a class `GenericReader`:

```scala
class GenericReader(spark: SparkSession, fileType: String) extends Serializable {
  def read(path: String): RDD[Result] = ???
}
```

Then when I call `new GenericReader(spark, "csv").read("myPath")` then it is able to derive that it has to read the data with `spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles` and apply the `CSVReader`. Or when it is `new GenericReader(spark, "bin").read("myPath")` then to create the RDD with `spark.sparkContext.binaryFiles` and apply `BINReader`.

I also tried to apply Implicit Design Pattern, but without success.
How can I solve this problem more elegantly?

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to do with a type class approach:

First the extra types which are necessary for the example:

```
object types {
  type Result = List[String]
  type PortableDataStream = String
}

import types._
```

Create the sealed trait(the coproduct):

```
sealed trait InputFileType
case object CSV extends InputFileType
case object JSON extends InputFileType
case object BIN extends InputFileType
```

Create your Reader type class which is represented as a trait with a type parameter:

```
trait Reader[A] {
  def doStep1: Seq[String]
  def process: Result
}
```

Create the companion object with includes the "summoner" method, and the instances that will be available at compile time:

```
object Reader {
  def apply[A <: InputFileType](implicit reader: Reader[A]) = reader

  implicit object CSVReader extends Reader[CSV.type] {
    override def doStep1: Seq[String] = {
      val list = Seq("I am csvReader")
      println(list)
      list
    }

    override def process: Result = List("Result Csv")
  }

  implicit object JSONReader extends Reader[JSON.type] {
    override def doStep1: Seq[String] = {
      val list = Seq("I am jsonReader")
      println(list)
      list
    }

    override def process: Result = List("Result Json")
  }

  implicit object BINReader extends Reader[BIN.type] {
    override def doStep1: Seq[String] = {
      val list = Seq("I am binReader")
      println(list)
      list
    }

    override def process: Result = List("Result Bin")
  }

}
```

Your GenericReader can be defined as:

```
class GenericReader[A](implicit reader: Reader[A]) {
   def process = reader.doStep1
}
```

To test the code:

```
object SparkReader {

  import Reader._

  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
    new GenericReader[CSV.type]().process
    new GenericReader[JSON.type]().process
    new GenericReader[BIN.type]().process
  }
}
```

prints:

```
List(I am csvReader)
List(I am jsonReader)
List(I am binReader)
```

There is a lot of info of how to work with type classes in Scala, Scalaz and Cats.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My main concern is that all the readers contain complex logic and implementation. If I'd put everything into the `object Reader`, then I'd obtain a huge object and that decreases the readability. Moreover, I was thinking to have the readers as submodules in the future, thus they can work independently. Thus, if I want to read only one file without Spark, then I am able to do it.